# My new DOM api: jquery-alike or with getters/setters?

Tags: java

I have built an event-base java html parser: [Lagarto](http://jodd.org/doc/lagarto/index.html). Now I am working on DOM builder, that creates a DOM tree using the parser. In the same time, I have developed CSS3 selectors node filter java library that works nice with this DOM tree.

My initial idea was to design DOM classes with API similar to **JQuery**. For example, to read an attribute user would call:

```
element.attr("name");
```

Similarly, to set an attribute user would call:

```
element.attr("name", "value");
```

However, this approach breaks the usual way how things are get and set in Java. Now I can't decide should I:

- build the jquery-alike API for my DOM classes. Together with CSS3 selectors library this would make everything very similar to **jquery**
- build the DOM classes using getters and setters. I am not sure if they would be ever used by some beanutil library, for example; and, for this purpose, it does not look so nice and fluent to me.

*Question*: what would you choose from above if you if you had to build your own DOM library?

Of course, there is no correct answer on this one:) Therefore I would accept the answer that matches my final decision - but that doesn't mean that the other solution is not correct!

Comment: If anyone wants to see the results: http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html

Comment: I hope this has been really successful for you. Java web apps having performance and flexibility crushed under the weight of a thousand libraries is something I'd like to see less of as a client-side JavaScript dev. Rapid DIY is immensely preferable to pre-fab solutions and that's what's truly appealing about tools like jQuery, IMO.

Comment: I also like to see (much:) less libs in java and more DIY work. Thats why I work on jodd project: to have the most of common stuff only in 1.1 Mb, with little dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better approach is to make both (surprisingly as in jquery, it's not just a DOM-library, but a wrapper around browser's DOM). So, you would have classical java objects with getters/setters for DOM and a $-library which wraps around the DOM objects to provide a fluent API.

It follows [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so the DOM objects are very simple and minimal, only required methods, setters/getters appear in the DOM API - ease of support and testing. And then you create a million of user-friendly $-wrappers to use the DOM-objects in less code.

**Update**

```
public class DomElement
{
  void insertChild(int pos, DomElement) {...}
  void setAttribute(String name, String value){...}
  String getAttribute(String name) {}
}
...
public class JQuery
{
  private final List<DomElement> els;
  public static JQuery $(DomElement ...e)
  {
     return new JQuery(Arrays.asList(e));
  }
  ...// some more methods which allow to create $-object with some other ways.

  private JQuery(List<DomElement> els)
  {
    this.els = els;
  }

  public String attr(String name)
  {
    return els.get(0).getAttribute(name);
  }
  public JQuery attr(String name, String value)
  {
    for(DomElement el : els)
      el.setAttribute(name, value);
    return this;
  }
...
}
```

And now we use it:

```
$(anElem1, anElem2)
  .attr("class", "myClass")
  .attr("width", w);
```

**From my experimental project**

There are several fragments, I hope it's enough to give an idea of the design.

```
public class JQuery
{

    private final List<HElement> es;
    private final JQuery parent;
    public interface Func<T>
    {
        T apply(final HElement element, final int index);
    }

    static public JQuery $(HElement e)
    {
        return new JQuery(null, e == null ? Collections.<HElement>emptyList() : Collections.singletonList(e));
    }

    static public JQuery $(Collection<HElement> es)
    {
            return new JQuery(null, new ArrayList<HElement>(es));
    }

    static public JQuery $(String selector, HElement e)
    {
            return new JQuery(null, e.selectAll(selector));
    }

    static public JQuery $(String selector, HtmLayout layout)
    {
            return new JQuery(null, layout.getRoot().selectAll(selector));
    }

    static public JQuery $(String selector, Collection<HElement> es)
    {
            final ArrayList<HElement> result = new ArrayList<HElement>();
            for(HElement e : es)
            {
                    result.addAll(e.selectAll(selector));
            }
            return new JQuery(null, result);
    }


    public JQuery find(String selector)
    {
        final ArrayList<HElement> result = new ArrayList<HElement>();
        for(HElement e : es)
            result.addAll(e.selectAll(selector));
        return new JQuery(this, result);
    }

    public JQuery text(String value)
    {
            for(HElement e : es)
            {
                    e.setInnerText(value);
            }
            return this;
    }

    public String text()
    {
            final StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
            for(HElement e : es)
            {
                    value.append(e.getInnerText());
            }
            return value.toString();
    }

    public int size()
    {
            return es.size();
    }
    public JQuery children()
    {
            final List<HElement> result = new ArrayList<HElement>(size());
            for(HElement e : es)
        for (HElement c : e.children())
            if(c!=null)// Avoid null TD in TR
                result.add(c);
            return new JQuery(this, result);
    }

    public JQuery children(String selector)
    {
            return children().filter(selector);
    }

    public JQuery filter(final String selector)
    {
            final List<HElement> result = new ArrayList<HElement>(size());
            for(HElement e : es)
            {
                    if(e.selectParentOrSelf(selector, 1) != null)
                            result.add(e);
            }
            return new JQuery(this, result);
    }


}
```

Comment: Interesting. This rises some new questions: user can choose if he wants to build simple DOM or $-wrapped DOM? Or, user decide later to wrap some simple DOM into $-wrapped classes? Should the wrapper class extend the simple DOM class, or just to wrap it?

Comment: Actually the $-object wraps an array of DOM-objects if you remember. So it could be a class. I update my answer for an example.

Comment: Cool. After some thinking, I like the idea; just want to see how to implement it in the best way. For example, I would like to avoid creating wrappers in runtime for every DOMobject (performances, memory).

Comment: You should not create it for all objects. Better if you look inside the jQuery and do something similar. E.g. if you use `attr` method to set attributes, you could return the same $-instance, however, if you use e.g. `parent()` it should return a new $-instance which wraps all dom-objects which are parents of the given. Also, keep in mind that the main design goal of the $-api is to be user-friendly, if one decides that it causes performance/memory issues he always could use pure DOM with no any additional costs.

Comment: I've made once something similar in an experimental project, I could provide you a bit more examples. But I hope you already have enough for a basic understanding.

Comment: You are right, this is what I was looking for. I was not ok to drop common get/set principle, yet wanted to have more fluent interface.

Comment: +1 all-around for seeing Java devs aiming for flexible/expressive interfaces over excessively rigid conventions meant to lower the bar. For a specialized adapter meant to handle a specific (but fairly large) subset of tasks in a specific domain, I don't think it's too much to ask for people to RTFM as long as the adapter's interface is fairly consistent in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how it's a Java API, I reckon the best thing to do — at least initially, should you decide later to provide both approaches as suggested by kan — is to adhere to Java conventions and provide an interface that will feel the most natural to Java developers. Not just in method naming, but also in overall design. The reason why libraries like DOM4J and JDOM exist is that the regular DOM API is intended to be language-independent and as such can feel unnatural for use in Java.

If there's one thing important for gaining traction in the use of a library/API, it's lowering the entry threshold and making users feel comfortable with it right away. Good design and usability will always trump matters like method naming or terseness, which should be of secondary importance.

If I see `element.attr("name", "value");`, it's not immediately clear to me whether this sets an attribute or attempts to get one's text, using `"value"` as a default in case it's not there. I'd have to check the documentation. But `element.getAttribute("name", "value");` gives me a much better guess, and `element.setAttribute("name", "value");` leaves nothing to the imagination. Java is verbose but is so by design... Java code reads like a story; when properly written it's accessible even if you're new to a piece of code.

Comment: This would make more sense to me if you wrote getAttribute as just having the first param. I actually like JQ's abstraction of getters and setters via overloading and I often use get/set method conventions in my app-level JS objects. For some reason it makes intuitive sense to just have the one method when dealing with DOM stuff. Probably because attributes and CSS properties only have one value to set. But also because the fundamental goal of JQ is to reduce DOM cruft. To adhere to Java conventions more strictly, I'd think you'd really want get/setIdAttribute, get/setClassAttribute, etc (ew).